# Are the origins of ¡ay, güey! and 'oy vey' related at all?

Tags: history, phrase-origin, loanwords, interjections, spanish

Though both of these terms come from other languages, they are both said in English, depending on where one is. [One](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ay%20wey) (ay wey as a more English form) can mean [holy crap!](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/%C2%A1Ay%2C%20g%C3%BCey!), and the other can mean [something similar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oy%20vey). Maybe it can be due to a [related](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish) [background](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sephardic_Jews)?

Comment: "¡Ay, güey!" is not used in English. Do you have its etymology? Also this question is extremely hard to follow without looking at all the links. Can you [edit] to make it clearer?

Comment: What is the related background that you suggest? Do you mean that both come from people who have been influenced by the Spanish?

Comment: Yes it is, a link shows it is used and I've heard it a gazillion times myself

Comment: I dispute that these are said in English. They're not even loan-words. They are foreign expressions uttered by English speakers.

Comment: English gets words from other languages, nothing new about that.

Comment: *oy veh* is Yiddish (from the German **weh**). It is said somewhat tongue-in-cheek by AmE speakers who are not themselves Jews.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. You say they are not said in English but are also said by English speakers.

Comment: Yes links show English usage and definitions and what languages they're from.

Comment: @user14094230 Yes, English is allowed to borrow words. But "Ay Guey" is _not_ one of the words it has borrowed. It is only mixed into English by bilinguals, particularly central Americans. Andrew Leach did not contradict himself. Don't be inflammatory.

Comment: Yes. They are not said in English. They are said in Yiddish and Spanish?/Portuguese? by English speakers.

Comment: Wrong they're said by native English speakers.

Comment: Well, I might say *Merde!* instead of a bit of Anglo-Saxon, but that doesn't make it an English expression. Sorry: these are not English expressions.

Comment: That's like saying klutz is not English or a ton if other words.

Comment: The argument that "that's not what English is like where I'm from" is ridiculous.

Comment: Your UD link calls the term "Mexican", and the SD link expressly says "translation", and a very bad translation it is!

Comment: If it's in the urban dictionary,  people use it in English. It says where it comes from. It's slang.

Comment: @user14094230 Urban Dictionary is not a reliable source for acceptability.

Comment: What do you mean acceptability? People say it in English, that's why it's there.

Comment: As far as etymology and usage goes there are two phrases here, and some of the categorical statements refer to them ambiguously. 'Oy Vey' (or more commonly just 'Oy' (which is not the same as the BrE version of 'Hey')) is very common in Northern New Jersey among non-Yiddish speakers (Jewish or not). I would consider it a part of English even if not used by all English speakers. As to 'Ay güey', i don't know at all, maybe it's used by non-Spanish speakers in the southwest US? (I don't think so but I don't know)

Comment: Yes it's a common term in the USA south west.

Comment: @user14094230 1) Please specify which 'it' you are referring to. Oy vey or ay güey? 2) But also, any ol person can add to Urban dictionary and they tend towards the ... superficial and lacking thought. UD is not an attempt at a scholarly source.

Comment: Ay wey is said in the USA south west. Oy vey is said more in the northeast, but people have tv, anyone may say it now.

Comment: @user14094230 I think your claims are in doubt and haven't been established to an extent that is acceptable to at least the other commenters here. Maybe your claims are reasonable to make, but I think most of the problem here that people are having is that if this question is on topic for ELU (because it is questionable if they are even English before one can question if they are related. Note they don't have the same meaning. Also note that experts in Yiddish/German -and- Spanish would be more likely to answer well... maybe [linguistics.se] is a better place for this?

Comment: What research have you done already? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%BCey says they're different. Wikipedia, while also a crowd sourced resource like UD, is somewhat more reliable (but still not optimal).

Comment: It doesn't 'mean' _holy crap_ - that's just an example of an expletive that someone thinks might be used in a similar context.

Comment: OK let's just be nice. While only tenuously English, this is an interesting question. Instead of quibbling, people can at least answer a lot of the issues.

Comment: A question about the relationship between Spanish and Yiddish terms probably belongs on Linguistics SE, although possibly you could ask for the origin of "ay, güey" on Spanish SE. Wikipedia gives rough etymologies for both, though you may like to trace it back a bit further yourself.

Comment: FYI 'holy crap' also doesn't actually mean blessed fecal matter is nearby

Comment: See also [Meta: questions involving a foreign language](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/how-to-treat-questions-involving-a-foreign-language) .

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of interesting issues here that all sort of are independent but related.

First:

- 'Oy vey' (pronounced /oj ve/) is an [expression of exasperation. It is a shortening of](https://www.etymonline.com/word/oy) (and loanphrase from) Yiddish: 'Oy weh is mir' = "Oh woe is me", "it pains me" ('weh' is cognate with English 'woe'). Yiddish is a common source of loanwords into English, more common in areas of Ashkenazi Jewish immigration in the US and UK. For example, you start to pour from a carton of milk on your cereal and only a dribble comes out. 'How annoying' or 'Oy vey' is an appropriate reaction. It is often shortened to 'Oy' (which is not to be confused with the BrE or Cockney 'Oy!' which is used to get someones attention and is just a phonologically altered 'Hey!'). Syntactically it is just an interjection in English.
- 'Ay güey' (pronounced /aj we/ or /aj ɣwe/) is a common phrase in Mexican Spanish. It seems to have been established that ['güey' comes from 'buey' which is from Latin  'bos' for cow](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/558/origin-of-the-mexican-expression-g%C3%BCey-buey). It is used as a very mild epithet, a little more spicy than just AmE 'pal' and 'buddy', or BrE 'mate'. Mexican Spanish is a common source of loanwords into English ('buckaroo' < 'vaquero', 'hoosegow' < 'juzgado').

(note: I am very unsure of its use in English (or Spanish) - I've never heard it as such but that doesn't mean English speakers don't use it especially in a geographical area with lots of Mexican Spanish speakers)

So they are not likely to be related in anyway. Surely there are transplants from Northern New Jersey to Texas (and vice versa) who might use both, but despite their superficial phonological and syntactic similarities, they are not used the same way and are not related in provenance.

Comment: I think it'd be interesting to see if Spanish 'No güey' comes from English 'No way!' or the other way round. Those are totally the same meaning.

Comment: That would then derive 'Sí güey' from 'No güey' rather than them both being in effect 'Yes/No, you idiot - it should be obvious'

Comment: @Henry Yes way?